# How to get latitude and longitude from video file in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gps

I need to extract GPS information from a video file, but I couldn't find any library that supports it. For images, I use the EXIF-JS library, but it doesn't support the MP4 and MOV formats.

Here is my video upload function, and I'm using ReactJS:

```
onUploadVideo = async (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload = 'metadata';
    const videoDuration = await new Promise(resolve => {
      video.onloadedmetadata = function () {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
        resolve(video.duration);
      }
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    });
    if (videoDuration >= ALLOW_VIDEO_DURATION) {
      this.props.actions.showToast(true, { toastType: ERROR, toastInfo: MESSAGE_ERROR_OVER_ALLOW_VIDEO_DURATION_UPLOAD.replace("%s", file.name) });
      return;
    }

    this.isUploadImg = true;
    this.setState({
      isUploadding: true
    })
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', file);

    this.props.actions.userFilePostActions(Actions.ActionTypes.UPLOAD_ADVENTURE_VIDEO(this.generateFileName('mp4')), data, getAccessToken(this.props.state.login_data));
  }
```

Comment: do mp4/mov files contain such metadata?

Comment: yes, my video file contain metadata

Comment: OK, so search for a library that extracts metadata from .mp4/.mov files for you